# Is there a way to have a mathematical function as the argument of a function in Python 3?

Tags: python

How can I include a mathematical function as an argument of a function in Python?

In my particular case, I'm writing a Riemann sum calculator that would ideally look like:

```
def riemann_sum(func_x, minvalue, maxvalue, partitions)
...
return riemannSum
```

where func_x is some function of x so that I could find the riemann sum of any arbitrary function this:

```
func_x = x**2
minvalue = 1
maxvalue = 2
partitions = 100
a = riemann_sum(func_x,minvalue,maxvalue,partitions)
print(a)
```

However, I can't do the above procedure because x is undefined.

I can get the Riemann sum for particular functions of x by manually typing it in to a line of my function that looks like:

```
someList = [x**2 for x in someOtherList]
```

Here, the function is x**2, but I can't change it without physically going in and changing the function.

My only solution right now is to define a new Riemann sum function every time I want to find the definite integral of a new function, which works but I feel like there's a better way.

(Edit: My question is different from the Riemann sum question marked as a possible duplicate. Their question is about an implementation specifically for a Riemann sum. My question is about how to incorporate a math function as the argument of a function, and I happen to use Riemann sum as a particular example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integration with Riemann Sum Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318682/integration-with-riemann-sum-python).  There are many options: just Google "python Riemann sum".  Here's another example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8BvG5MKpzU.  Or this: http://rojok.github.io/riemann-sums-in-python.html

Comment: Are you talking about `func_x = lambda x: x**2` ?

Comment: yeah... I sort of forgot about the lambda function. That is what I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python functions are first class objects so you can, for example, pass functions as arguments to other functions.  That is, the way you wrote your `riemann_sum` function declaration is fine.

What doesn't work is your definition of `func_x`, since you need to define `func_x` as a function.  For that you can either do:

```
func_x = lambda x: x**2
```

or, for a more general multiline (or single line) function

```
def func_x(x):
    temp = x**2  # just to stretch this out to another line for demonstration
    return temp
```

Then you can say something like:

```
def riemann_sum(func_x, minvalue, maxvalue, partitions):
    # below just demos calling func_x, and is a bad way to do the sum
    riemannSum = 0
    step = 1.0*(maxvalue-minvalue)/partitions
    value = minvalue
    while value<maxvalue:
        riemannSum == step*func_x(value)  # here's where func_x is called
        value += step
    return riemannSum
```

That is, the main point here is that is demonstrates how to call `func_x` within the `riemann_sum` function.  This allows you to evaluate `func_x` at different x-values, as required to evaluate the sum.

Comment: Okay, I think this is what I wanted. Python now doesn't have a problem with my function of x, but for some reason this unearthed a problem with some other code that worked just fine before. I'll assume I can fix that problem on my own. The lambda function seems to be the key that I was missing, thanks!.

Comment: `lambda` works, but keep in mind that the more general and versatile is to just define a function.  I just put it in to be complete, but I almost always use the regular function, and only use lambdas when I use the function on the same line I write it, such as a one-off call, like `riemannSum(lambda x: x**2, 1, 2, 100)`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this is another (less prominent) problem I wanted solved. I want to be lazy and just type the function of X directly into my Riemann sum function, without having to define a new function every time I'm entering a new function of X. Lambda helps me to be slightly lazier, but defining the function is the real problem I had.

Comment: Right.  That seems like a reasonable use case.  I just wanted to be clear that it's more the exception than the norm.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Replace with whatever your function is  
def func_x(x):
    return x**2


def riemann_sum(func_x(3), minvalue, maxvalue, partitions)
...
return riemannSum
```

This should do it. You can create the function elsewhere, then initialize it in your riemann_sum as an input.

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem... by saying func_x(3) I have specified that I'm evaluating my function only at x = 3... or 3**2 = 9. I need to evaluate my function at a specific number (given by the partitions argument) of positions between minvalue and maxvalue. Setting x=3 (or any number) confines x to a single value when I need it to be sampled at many values..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few years back when I was coding something for my differential equations class. Here is an example of what worked for me:

```
func_x = "(x**2)+x+1"
paramList = [(1+(1/k),(1/k)-(1/(k+1))) for k in range(1,101)]
# paramList holds the tuple (x,changeInX) for the riemann sum
def riemann_sum(str_func_x,paramList):
    theSum=0
    for tup in paramList:
        x=tup[0]
        diff=tup[1]
        theSum+=eval(str_func_x)*diff
    return theSum
riemannSumValue = riemann_sum(func_x,paramList)
```

Make sure that param list is really from 1,1+1/100, . . ., 2 for the first index
of the tuples in paramList. . . I think it is from 1.01 to 2 as it is now (I took some tylenol pm 20 minutes ago and now I am too tired to check myself.)

Comment: Okay thanks! While someone already answered my main question, this solves a secondary problem I had. Namely, the "eval" function helps a lot because it allows me to enter the function as a string and then "unstring" it when I need it evaluated.